# How to disable admin port in DropWizard while using gzip server mode/type

Tags: gzip, dropwizard

I am trying to disable admin port in DropWizard while using 'gzip' server mode.
I know this is possible in 'simple' server. Below is the .yml file configuration. -

```
server:
  type: simple
```

but I want to disable admin port in gzip server mode.

```
server:
  gzip:
    bufferSize: 8KiB
```

NOTE: I cant use 'simple' server as we have dependency on 'gzip'.
 I am out of ideas now any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default Dropwizard config includes an admin connector. To prevent this, you will need to explicitly tell it to not include any admin connectors:

```
server:
  gzip:
    bufferSize: 8KiB
  adminConnectors: []
```